# 20.713316 intel-rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0 error and Ubuntu /Xubuntu does not boot..message is permanent

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, xubuntu

I have managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my MAC OS the first time. I used Virtual Box. However, when I upgraded my Mac to Mac OS Sierra I was constantly receiving this message 20.713316 intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains in package 0.

I was told that this was a power problem that maybe my laptop's processeur is unable to run this OS. I have closed all applications during installment but to no avail.

I tried downloading Xubuntu - first time it worked wonders then I noticed I had some missing packages and features so I réinstalled it and again the same problem appeared.

Do you think I should upgrade my Ram and processor if possible?

I have read the messages concerning this error but my system does not boot to Xubuntu or Ubuntu unlike what other users have experienced.

To my knowledge I have followed the disk partitioning to the letter - my system runs on 1.6GHZ and has 4GB Ram and 256GB hard drive....so now I'm opting for Xubuntu because the latest version of Ubuntu requires at least 2GHZ processor.

I have allocated 1.7 GB for my virtual Ram and 10GB for my virtual hard drive..

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution for this bug. Try to enable the function "Intel Virtualization Technology", on the BIOS SETUP. Step by step in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=886cH0E-T7I